# count highest occurance category-wise in sql select statement

Tags: mysql

I have a table from which i want to COUNT highest no of occurrence category-wise and output that specific entry only.

I tried this query but no luck
    $sql="  SELECT category,article,COUNT(*)
        FROM articles_likes
        WHERE category = '{$category}'
        GROUP BY article
        DESC";

for eg:

table -

```
article category
1         A
1         B
1         B
2         A
2         A
2         B
3         A
4         B
```

Expected output -

If I select A then it should be 2

If I select B then it should be 1

Comment: Honestly, I can't understand that. How does your table look like?

Comment: Sorry @ThomasKilian i changed the table...hope u may understand this..thanks

Comment: Please add table schema (maybe with example of table content) and show your SQL query which doesn't do what you want but displays your intention.

Comment: Dont you have b=4 and a=3 so it should be 1 and 1?

Comment: @Mihai I want category wise article highest no of occurrence..Answer from Andrew JOnes is bang on but also want to know how to display total count with it please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to sort the articles in descending order of their counts for a category. Limiting the query to a single record will give you the article with the most counts. For A, the following query will work. Note that I have used `table` as the table name because the question didn't provide the table name.

```
SELECT article
FROM table
WHERE category = 'A'
GROUP BY article
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If you need more information than just the article, then you can add the following to your select statement for more details.

```
SELECT article, category, COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE category = 'A'
GROUP BY article
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Perfect @Andrew Jones..thanks one last question how do I display the total count of the highest occurrence article? I know i might be sounding very stupid but my brain isn't function properly at this time...i guess it got exhausted ;)

Comment: Got this right but how to display total count with it $records= $mysqli->query($sql);


while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($records)) {
 $articles [] = $row;
 

 echo "" . $row['article'] . "";

Comment: Are you looking for the total count for the article within the category or the total count across the whole table?

Comment: Thanks Andrew..For article..I was able to figure that out...thank you so much for the rescue..cheers!!!